# TYPO3 7.6 LTS change width of categories window (Select tree /Backend / TCA)

Tags: typo3, backend, categories, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Is it possible to change the width of the categories select tree. Since `TYPO3 7.6 LTS` the width is limited to `280px`, so you need to scroll, if you've lots of TYPO3-categories (Page properties -> categories). Earlier it was at `100%`. Maybe there's some manipulating with the `TCA` via `TypoScript`? But I don't know how.

I found a task, so maybe it's fixed in `TYPO3 8 LTS` but I can't update my current project. https://forge.typo3.org/issues/77081

Thanks for your help.

[image: typo3 categories select tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can rewrite the TCA part for sys_categories, the tree config supports a custom with in **PX**.

Read here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/6.2/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#treeconfig

If you want 100% width, there is a easier way with a own backend skin css file. Just register a folder for backend css files in your extension or theme extension `ext_tables.php` file:

```
$TBE_STYLES['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['name'] = $_EXTKEY;
$TBE_STYLES['skins'][$_EXTKEY]['stylesheetDirectories']['structure'] = 'EXT:' . ($_EXTKEY) . '/Resources/Public/Backend/Css/Skin/';
```

Place therein a css file with this content:

```
div.x-tree {
    width: 100%!important;
}

div.x-tree .x-panel-tbar {
    width: 100%!important;

}
div.x-tree .x-panel-tbar .x-toolbar {
    width: 100%!important;
}

div.x-tree .x-panel-body {
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

Clear caches and reload backend. The tree should be rendered with 100%. This affect all configured tree views in your backend. There is no selector to select only sys_categories tree views.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Manfred. Thank you very much. I've made it with my own stylesheet, like you're explained.